# Get rid of Compatibility Mode warning

Tags: ms-word, word-2013

I use RTF as the default format. Is there a way to keep Word 2013 from showing “[Compatibility Mode]” after the title of every document? It is taking up lots of space in the taskbar and title bar and makes the titles of documents hard to read.

Comment: I eventually gave up and switched to DOCX. I notice my files are about a third the size. I only hope the format is around a long long time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to suppress using a setting - RTF file format hasn't been the "plain text" version of a Word document since Word 2007, when the Word Open XML format took over that role. Any RTF file equates to Compatibillity Mode since it cannot support the newer Word functionality.

The only possibility you'd have would be to set the Caption property of the Application object, using VBA or another language automating the Word application. But you need to be aware that this is not permanent in any way.